# “headers already sent” message, issue in WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have created a WordPress plugin. while i am going to activate the plugin facing following error:

> The plugin generated 250 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

I have checked for white spaces and characters before the PHP starting tag and closing tag.
But error remains.

Comment: (1) Post your plugin's install script, (3) set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your config file, (3) check for syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all comment lines and fill the white spaces in the entire program code. This may help.

Answer (score 0):

You remove the php close tag ( ?> ) from end of every file ;

when you activate the plugin just check if table already exist or not .

i remove the issue by  the code

```
    if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name}(
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            name VARCHAR(250),
            email VARCHAR(250),
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
        );";
        dbDelta($sql);
    }
```